# Access WordPress widget options on registered sidebars through AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am in need to get widget options available in sidebars of WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built following code for accessing widget options through ajax.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_sidebar_widget_info', 'get_sidebar_widget_info');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_sidebar_widget_info', 'get_sidebar_widget_info');

function get_sidebar_widget_info(){
header('Content-Type: application/Json');
global $wp_registered_widgets;

$response = array();
$sidebars_widget_list = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
unset($sidebars_widget_list['array_version']);

foreach($sidebars_widget_list as $sidebar_id => $widget_list){
    foreach($widget_list as $widget_id){
        $widget_option_name = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['callback'][0]->option_name;
        $widget_number = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['params'][0]['number'];
        $widget_options = get_option($widget_option_name);
        $response[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_id] = $widget_options[$widget_number];
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
wp_die();
```

}